# how can I store the intermediate result in pyspark reduceByKey function?

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

This is a case for calculating average hold cost. We only consider the trades that increase the account balance, regardless of the trades that decrease the account balance.

```
# data example: ((1,'000001'),('A',0,5000,5000)),
# (1,'000001') is the groupby key , 'A' is order by key (serialno) , '0' is the account balance
# before the trade, '5000' is trade balance, '5000' is the account balance aftre the trade. We aim
# to calculate #the average cost per unit after the trades in each group by spark rdd.

confirm = [
    ((1, '000001'), ('A', 0, 5000, 5000)),
    ((1, '000001'), ('C', 9000, 1000, 10000)),
    ((1, '000001'), ('B', 5000, 5000, 9000)),
    ((2, '000001'), ('D', 0, 3300, 3000)),
    ((2, '000001'), ('F', 4000, 5000, 10000)),
    ((2, '000001'), ('E', 3000, 4200, 6000)),
    ((3, '000001'), ('G', 0, 3300, 3000)),
    ((3, '000001'), ('H', 3000, 3300, 6300))
]


def my_partition(x):
    return x[0] % 3


def partSort(x):
    xlist = list(x)
    a = sorted(xlist, key=lambda x: x[1][0])
    return iter(a)


import pandas as pd


def udf_func(x, y):
    if y is None:

        result = x[2] / x[3]
        df = pd.DataFrame([{'serialno': x[0], 'result': result}])
    else:
        result = (
                         (x if isinstance(x, float) else (x[2] / x[3])) * y[1] + y[2]
                 ) / y[3]

        df = pd.DataFrame([{'serialno': y[0], 'result': result}])
    # this is where I want to store the intermediate result,but does not work eg:
    df.to_csv("/home/zo_om/result.csv", 'a')
    return result


rdd = sc.parallelize(confirm).partitionBy(3, my_partition). \
    mapPartitions(partSort).reduceByKey(udf_func)
rdd.collect()
```

After I run the code, the result is:

```
[
 ((3, '000001'), 1.0476190476190477),
 ((2, '000001'), 1.0),
 ((1, '000001'), 1.1)
]
```

which is last result of each group.

***I can see only 1 row in the "/home/zo_om/result.csv" ( only in one work node of spark cluster, zo_om is 
 the kerberos user). What I expect to see is 8 rows ( one for each serialno （'A'~'H'） )***

Comment: in fact, this problem can be simplified to : if we have n rows：R1,R2,R3,...Rn-1,Rn .Each row has 2 elements . Ri[0],Ri[1] .  Now, we want to calculate a new element for each row, the formular is :   Rn[2] = Rn-1[2]*Rn[0]+Rn[1]   while the initial value R1[2]=R1[1]/R1[0] . I want to get the result as soon as possible ,as less cost as possible in spark clustser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you only see one line since `pd.DataFrame.to_csv` overwrites the existing data and you write to the same path all the time

Comment: thanks, my fault,I changed the to_csv(mode='a'), and I managed to see 8 rows in result.csv file.But I still have a question.why does it write to the same path all the time? does it mean that writing to csv file will be the bottleneck of process when the dataset is very large?

Comment: It's the same path all the time since you hard-coded it. For bigger data this might be a bottleneck. Try looking into the spark sql dataframe API and the df.write.csv() option. You might also find a way to avoid the UDF altogether